# Problems after creating mdadm RAID-1: disk identifier 0x00000000 and same serial number on both disks

Tags: hard-disk, mdadm, fdisk, raid1

I need your help with a problem that I’ve been trying to solve for days now. 
I recently purchased a Western Digital (WD) My Book Duo, and after setting it to make it work as two independent disks I wanted to create a Linux-based RAID system.
Basically, I tried to create an encrypted RAID-1 array (using the 2 disks) for storing purposes with the following structure:

> RAID-1 > LUKS → LVM → ext4

This was the first time that I created a RAID but I have chosen this (somewhat complex) structure
because I followed a forum thread that was quite convincing to me. 
The process went well and everything was seeming to work fine
until I discovered that something odd was happening with my disks. 
I have the following problems:

**Problem 1**

When I tried using `smartctl` in order to do a test on the disks,
I realized that my system was seeing the two disks
(being in `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`) as if they were the same drive. 
Indeed, the output of:
`smartctl -a /dev/sdb` and
`smartctl -a /dev/sdc`
is exactly the same. Identical. 
Also, the serial numbers of the two disks are the same!!
(overlapping with the serial number of 1 of the 2 indeed). 
The same happens if I use the `hdparm -I` command. 
How can this happen?  Do you have any idea? 
Is this due to the activation of the RAID-1? 
If that is the case, how I will be able to eventually substitute 1 of the 2 disks in the case it fails if the system is seeing both as being the same?

**Problem 2**

If I run:

```
fdisk -l
```

I see some weird things:

- disk identifier for both disks is = 0x00000000
- it gives me a warning
  saying: “Partition 1 does not start on a physical sector boundary.”

I have read [on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/how-to-fix-partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary-warning) that point 2 can be due to the fact that
Western Digital disks now use Advanced Format 4096-byte sectors,
but I don’t know if I have to worry about it. 
What is sure is that being the disk identifier = 0x00000000
it’s rather concerning. 
Any help, suggestion, or hint is very appreciated! 
As a reference I leave you here the list of commands I executed to build the RAID:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
cat /proc/mdstat    (waited several hours for the process to complete the sync)
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/md0
cryptsetup open /dev/md0 my_crypt_raid
pvcreate /dev/mapper/my_crypt_raid
vgcreate my_raid_vg /dev/mapper/my_crypt_raid
lvcreate -l +100%FREE my_raid_vg -n my_raid_lv
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_raid_lv
mnt /dev/mapper/my_raid_lv /mnt/my_raid
```

Comment: use partitions instead of whole disks in mdadm

Comment: @frostschutz, thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate it. Could you please tell me which kind of partition table and partition would you suggest to use at the basis of mdadm (instead of the whole disk) and how can I achieve those?